# Interactive console plug-in for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, console

I am trying to create a plug-in in eclipse that can create a console and take input from user
I have a code..

```
    MessageConsole console=new MessageConsole("MyConsole", null);
    console.activate();
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[]{console});
    MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
    stream.println("Hello Eclipse");
```

But this console is not interactive. Is there any way to make it interactive.

OR

Is it possible to use default console of eclipse for user interaction using plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean getting user input from the console view, you can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class or the [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class.

Code sample:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = reader.next();
```

Or

```
Console console = System.console();
String userInput = console.readLine("Please input:");
```

Comment: By using scanner or console class neither I am able to write on eclipse console nor I can convert msgconsole in to interactive console......